# Elegant way of getting a power-of-2-related result

Tags: c

First-off, sorry for the vague title. Here's my problem:

Let `n > 0` be a natural number. Determine the positive number `k` such that `2^i + k = n` for the largest possible `i`.

How would I do this in C elegantly?

Comment: You mean how would _we_ do it elegantly in C? ;)

Comment: Please specify your question more or make at least an example.

Comment: This looks like a trivial assignment question.  For your own sake, you should work it out yourself.  There's only a handful of operators in C...

Comment: k = n - 2^Floor(Log2(n))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int i = 0; j = 1, k, n = (your value);

if ( n > 0 )
{
    while ( 2 * j < n) 
    {
        j = 2 * j; 
        i++;
    }

    k = n - j;
}

// replace '<' with '<=' if k = 0 is desired where n is a pure power of 2
```

(nb: there is no exponentiation operator in Standard C)

Comment: Why is int capitalized?

Answer (score 2):

Elegance is in the mind of the beholder.

```
unsigned long find_remnant(unsigned long n) {
  for (unsigned long j, k = 0;
       (j = n&-n) != n;
       n -= j, k += j ) {
  }
  return k;
}
```

This is based on the fact that `n&-n` is the lowest-order `1` bit in the binary representation of n. So the loop strips off the one-bits from n, one at a time, accumulating them in k, until only a single one-bit is left, which must be 2^i.

Since the loop executes once per set bit in `n`, rather than once per bit in `n`, it might be faster.

In case it is an issue, since `0&-0` is 0, if called with an argument of `0` (contrary to the problem specification), the function will simply return `0`, which is not an unreasonable result.

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long fn(unsigned long n) {
    int x;
    frexp(n, &x);
    return n - (1UL << (x-1)); }
```

Note that this will fail for n == 0 (giving an undefined result), but you did specify n > 0

Comment: you're almost there, the question requires k > 0

Comment: @Jasen: the question says "positive k", which normally means k >= 0

Comment: they would have said non-negative if they meant to include 0, 0 is not positive

Comment: 0 is neither positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the largest power of 2 less than n. (by rounding down log2n) Call the number x.
2. The `k` you want to find is `n - 2^x.`

**OR**

You can write a loop that checks every power of two less than n.

The first method is faster. (constant time vs. O(n) time)

Comment: you forgot to subtract 1 before doing log2 -- k must be positive

Comment: "the first method **is** faster" — now that's a bit of a blind assertion.

Comment: Okay I will make some corrections. Thanks. @Jasen

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Okay just added some justification.

Comment: What do you mean by "subtract 1 before doing log2" @Jasen

Comment: the answer should be greater than 0 , never equal zero, s0 `log2(n-1)`